# Does React.lazy() works with Create React App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-lazy-load

I have created one React App using **npx create-react-app my-app** cmd (**React 17 version**). Now
Well, I just tried to replace a classic

```
import Component from './Component'

to

const Component = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));

and then

<React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading.. </div>}>
    <Component />
</React.Suspense>
```

but it throws error like
SyntaxError: Unexpected token at import(6:22)

```
> 6 |  const Component = React.lazy(() => import('./Component'));
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

This is the code syntax
[image]

And this is the suspense component
[image]

And this is the compilation output
[image]

My package.json looks like

[image]

Comment: I have a full routing file with every component is imported using React.lazy and its a create react app and i am also using React.Suspense and its working completely fine. are you importing React right? :p other than that it might be a type or syntax error

Comment: Please check I have updated the question with my exact code and some snapshots.

Comment: Do we need any extra setup to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this fixes your issue, but maybe you can give it a try. Are you using `Babel`?

It says:

> When using Babel, you’ll need to make sure that Babel can parse the
> dynamic import syntax but is not transforming it. For that you will
> need @babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import.

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import

I've created a `.babelrc` file on the project root and added the content:

```
{
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

I also imported `lazy` in my component:

```
import React, { Component, lazy, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
```

In my project `React.lazy` is working fine this way.

Comment: Let me check this and will back to you.

Comment: No, I am not using babel

Comment: Created react app using create-react-app cmd